# install php5-imagick for PHP 5.4.17-1~precise+1

Tags: php, apache2, dependencies

I am trying to install imagemagick on my ubuntu 12.04 server.

my php version is PHP 5.4.17-1~precise+1
and installed imagemagick Version: 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2

but installing php5-imagick is compromising my php5 version i think:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjson-c2{a} php5-json{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php5-common php5-imagick 
2 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
Need to get 595 kB of archives. After unpacking 185 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
 php5-gd : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
 php5-xmlrpc : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
 php5-mcrypt : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
 php5-mysql : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
 php5-cli : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.17-1~precise+1) but 5.5.4+dfsg-1+debphp.org~precise+1 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:              
1)      libapache2-mod-php5                       
2)      php5                                      
3)      php5-cli                                  
4)      php5-curl                                 
5)      php5-gd                                   
6)      php5-mcrypt                               
7)      php5-mysql                                
8)      php5-xmlrpc                               
9)      phpmyadmin                                

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
10)     libapache2-mod-php5 recommends php5-cli
```

Have tried installing php5-imagick=3.1.0~rc1-1

but it says

```
php5-imagick : Depends: phpapi-20090626 which is a virtual package.
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: This is better asked on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable) ppa ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable;

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5-dev

sudo pecl install imagick
```